# Python Guessing Game not doing what I want it to do

Tags: python

Bear with me, I am a beginner.

Here is my code for a simple version of Guessing Game. I know that it can be written in a way more efficient way, but please help and let me know why what I wrote isn't working. Not matter what letter I type, `h`, or `l`, it keeps on looping over the first letter that I picked.

```
high = 100
low = 0
guess = ((low + high) / 2)

print("Please think of a number between" + str(high) + " and " + str(low))

answer = input("Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?\n"
                                                       "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is "
                                                       "too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess "
                                                       "is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I "
                                                       "guessed correctly.")

while guess != 0:
    if answer == "h":
        high = guess
        guess = ((low + high) / 2)
        input("Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?\n"
                                                  "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is "
                                                  "too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess "
                                                  "is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I "
                                                  "guessed correctly.")
    elif answer == "l":
        low = guess
        guess = ((low + high) / 2)
        input("Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?\n"
                                                  "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is "
                                                  "too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess "
                                                  "is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I "
                                                  "guessed correctly.")
    elif answer == "c":
        print("Game over. Your secret number was " + str(guess))
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, I did not understand your input."
              "Is your secret number " + str(guess) + "?\n"
                                                      "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is "
                                                      "too high. Enter 'l' to indicate the guess "
                                                      "is too low. Enter 'c' to indicate I "
                                                      "guessed correctly.")
```

Comment: You're not assigning to `answer` when you ask for input inside the while loop. So it keeps using the first answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I feel quite stupid now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the line `answer = input("Is your secret number ...")` inside the while loop, so that each time, the program gets a new input. This would be:

```py
...
while guess != 0:
    answer = input("Is your secret number ...")
    if answer == 'h':
        ...
```

I also recommend you use f-strings to print out numbers, so instead of:

```py
print("Please think of a number between" + str(high) + " and " + str(low))
```

you can just write:

```py
print(f"Please think of a number between {high} and {low}")
```

To learn more about f-strings, check out [this](https://datagy.io/python-f-strings/) page.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I feel quite stupid now :)  Thanks for the info on f-strings, looks great and super useful, I will look into it now.